# Возвращает (-1) при чтении из потока

Tags: c++, windows, filestream, bmp, fstream

Читаю из файла `.BMP` массив пикселей, который верен по размеру, если верить заголовку файла.

```
void img::read_bimg(char ** &smth, unsigned int bfOfBits,
                        unsigned int biX,
                        unsigned int biY) // biX, biY (512) - высота и ширина в
                                          //пикселях, в соответствии с заголовком файла.
                                          // bfOFBits (1078) - начало пикселей в файле.
    {
        imgf.seekg(bfOfBits, std::ios::beg);
        std::cout << imgf.tellg() << std::endl; // Выдает 1078, что верно.
                                              // С этого места начинаются сами пиксели.
        for (unsigned int y = 0 ; y < biY ; y++) {
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < biX ; x++) {
                unsigned char buf;
                imgf.read((char*)&buf, sizeof(char));
                smth[y][x] = buf;

            }
        }       

        std::cout<< imgf.tellg() << std::endl; // -1 
    }
```

Всегда возвращал `-1` при `tellg`, из-за чего я думал, что был конец файла, то есть флаг `eofbit`. Но проверив с помощью нехитрого хода:

```
imgf.seekg(0, std::ios::end); 
imgf.tellg;
```

Получил значение `263222`, что чуть больше `(512*512)`. Так что конца файла не может быть, скорее всего это `failbit`. Но что программа могла встретить в файле такого, что в поток установился флаг ошибки?

А так же с помощью костыля `clear()` я сбрасываю флаг и избавляюсь от этой **ошибки**.

---

**UPD**:Файл был открыт без флага `binary`.

Comment: Сам кусок кода в общем то валидный, вопрос, что этому методу на вход попадает. Например некорректные biX или biY.

Comment: Я указал: `biX, biY (512)`.

Comment: Ещё на всякий случай - ряды пикселей в bmp выравниваются до размера, кратного 4 байтам. Т.е. ваш код будет работать корректно, только если ширина картинки кратна четырем (пиксель, так понимаю у вас 8-ми битный в bmp).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, да, восьмибитный. 512 кратен 4.

Comment: Может у вас файл в текстовом режиме открыт, и вы под Windows запускаете?

Comment: В случае если файл открыт в текстовом режиме под Windows, если в файле встретятся байты 0x0D 0x0A, они будут заменены на 0x0A, т.е. полезный размер файла сократится, и конец наступит раньше чем ожидалось.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, да. Именно в текстовом и был открыт. Это исправило ситуацию. Просто я думал, что если читаю с помощью `read`, то он автоматически считает его двоичным.